# How to derive this ODE formula?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can we derive this ODE property? "D" represents a differential operator, I am unable to find any sort of derivation for this please help me out.

${1\over{D-a}}f(x)=e^{ax}\int{e^{-ax}f(x)}dx$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This means $D^{-1}(f(x))=\int f(x) dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, using the product rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus, you have
$$
(D-a)\left(e^{ax}\int e^{-ax}f(x)dx\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{ax}\int e^{-ax}f(x)dx\right)-ae^{ax}\int e^{-ax}f(x)dx=
$$
$$
=ae^{ax}\int e^{-ax}f(x)dx+e^{ax}e^{-ax}f(x)-ae^{ax}\int e^{-ax}f(x)dx=f(x).
$$